# Perl script for aligning corpora

Tags: perl

So I'm trying to figure out what this perl script does.

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use strict;
use Encode;

binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
binmode(STDERR, ":utf8");

chdir($Bin);
my $dir = "txt";
my $outdir = "aligned";
my $preprocessor = "$Bin/tools/split-sentences.perl -q";

my ($l1,$l2) = @ARGV;
die unless -e "$dir/$l1";
die unless -e "$dir/$l2";

`mkdir -p $outdir/$l1-$l2/$l1`;
`mkdir -p $outdir/$l1-$l2/$l2`;

my ($dayfile,$s1); # globals for reporting reasons
open(LS,"ls $dir/$l1|");
while($dayfile = <LS>) {
  chop($dayfile);
  if (! -e "$dir/$l2/$dayfile") {
    print "$dayfile only for $l1, not $l2, skipping\n";
    next;
  }
  &align();
}
```

From looking at this I need to run

```
perl sentence-align-corpus.perl europarlEnglishCorpus.txt europarlSpanishCorpus.txt
```

where those two files are in a txt folder.

Running the above gives me

```
txt/europarlEnglishCorpus.txt only for europarlEnglishCorpus.txt, not europarlSpanishCorpus.txt, skipping
```

And doesn't align sentences, it just creates directories. It looks like that if is being triggered, but I'm not sure what it does.

What does this script do?

Comment: I feel this needs input from the author of the program. I would look further on the site you downloaded it and if need be send an email.

Comment: :( http://www.statmt.org/europarl/ doesn't seem to be much help

Comment: What real problem are you trying to solve. This program may or may not do it as its purpose is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command-line parameters are *directories*. The program expects to find files in `txt/p1` and `txt/p2` (where `p1` and `p2` are the parameters passed).

It checks all the files in `txt/p1` and either prints the error message you see if there if there is no file of the same name in `txt/p2`, or calls the `align` subroutine.

You are presumably getting the results you see because there is a file `txt/europarlEnglishCorpus.txt` but not one at `txt/europarlSpanishCorpus.txt/europarlEnglishCorpus.txt`.

The confusion arises because the program lists the directories by shelling out to `ls`, which will take either a filename or a directory name as its parameter.

Beyond this I cannot help you.

Comment: I think the main reason for the confusion is that the script only checks whether the arguments exist by `-e` instead of checking they are actually directories with `-d`. But i would assume you are right, the script wants to align two "dayfiles", whatever that is, which are in different, passed as arguments, directories but have the same name.

Comment: @DeVadder: Yes, a `-d` test would help. But there's no reason to shell out to `ls` when `opendir` / `readdir` do all that's required. And it is aligning two *sets* of “dayfiles” that it pairs up by finding files of the same name in the two specified directories. Again, a `-f` test would be better here.

Comment: We are trying to work out what the script does. Until we have done that, trying to refactor to improve style is premature IMHO

Comment: @justintime: The point is that the purpose of the program would be more obvious had it been written a little better. Passing file names as parameters instead of directory names should produce an error message. Instead, the program pretends to be working.

Answer (score 3):

The program is assuming the following input in the same directory as the .pl file

```
txt/
  lang-a/
     day-1
     day-2
  lang-b/
     day-1
     day-2
  lang-c/
     day-1
     day-2
```

and you then run it as

./sentence-align-corpus.perl  lang-a  lang-b

I assume that the files mentioned at http://www.statmt.org/europarl/ under Download might be of interest.

There are pointers on this website. These may or may not be helpful, but I would expect you to have read these before asking SO for help.

> For a detailed description of this corpus, please read:
>
> - Europarl: A Parallel Corpus for Statistical Machine Translation, Philipp Koehn, MT Summit 2005, pdf.
> - Please cite the paper, if you use this corpus in your work. See also
>     the extended (but earlier) version of the report (ps, pdf).

I stick to my original suggestion,  email the address given on the website and ask for better instructions as to what else (if anything) you need to download, how to run it and what it aims to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the second argument (i.e. `europarlSpanishCorpus.txt`) you give to this script is wrong, it expects it to be a directory under the directory named `txt`.